# Pokédex by a Python novice

Tags: python, beginner, pokemon

This is my first real personal application and I'm just looking for some outside feedback.
Completely built in Python, this is a Pokédex for the Pokémon Mystery Dungeon series.
I hope to eventually publish to the Android app store.
If you choose to check it out... don't be nice. Tell me how bad it is, (just make sure you tell me how to fix it too).

```
import os, json
from assets.utilities.pokeapi import api
from assets.data.models.pokemon import Pokemon
class Version:
    def __init__(dex, name):
        dex.basepath = "assets/data/storage/json/"
        dex.name = name
        dex.version = dex.getversion()
        dex.pokemon = dex.version['pokemon']
        dex.pokedex = []
    def getversion(dex):
        versionpath = f"{dex.basepath}versions/{dex.name}.json"
        if os.path.exists(versionpath):
            with open(versionpath) as file:
                file = file.read()
                version = json.loads(file)
        return version
    def getpokemon(dex):
        count = 1
        for pokemon in dex.pokemon:
            dexid = pokemon['dexid']
            species = pokemon['species']
            path = f"{dex.basepath}pokemon/{species}.json"
            with open(path) as file:
                file = file.read()
                pokemon = json.loads(file)
            try:
                typing = pokemon['typing']
                abilities = pokemon['abilities']
                moveset = pokemon['moveset']
            except:
                stop = len(dex.pokemon)
                # stop = 9
                if count <= stop:
                    data = api.pokemon(dexid, species)
                    print(f'requesting {count} of {stop}')
                    typing = data.typing()
                    abilities = data.abilities()
                    moveset = data.moveset()
                    pokemon.update({'typing': typing, 'abilities': abilities, 'moveset': moveset})
                    pokemon = json.dumps(pokemon)
                    with open(path, 'w') as file:
                        file.write(pokemon)
                    count += 1
                else:
                    break
            else:
                pokemon = Pokemon(pokemon)
                dex.pokedex.append(pokemon)
        return
```

The rest is
GitHub repo: [https://github.com/austenc-id/MysteonDex/](https://github.com/austenc-id/MysteonDex/tree/b30729041fc2d73df76fc4c574ab653c0ce46e34)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The site's rules require that you embed the code that you wish to be reviewed in the question itself. You can post a GitHub link for supplementary context, but you have posted so little code in the question that the reviews are unlikely to be meaningful.

Comment: This question is incomplete, and even your GitHub repo is incomplete. There are no clear entry points, and the code that initializes `storage` is missing.